# Word to describe a set of financial actions (send, withdraw, deposit, receive money)

Tags: gui-design, wording

I am working on a mobile wallet application.

What would be a better word to use to describe the following page and correlating set of financial actions.

"**Transact**" sounds weird...

[image]

Comment: These are types of trans**actions**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the word **"Transaction"** instead of **"transact"**... its more communicating in case of user prospective. and you can use the word **"Banking"** or **"Bank"** instead of that.

Here  i attached a image hope it will work well for you :)

[image]